# Do I need to use HeapLock and HeapUnlock functions in winapi whenever I want to use HeapAlloc or HeapFree?

Tags: windows, winapi, memory-management

Do I need to use HeapLock and HeapUnlock functions in winapi whenever I want to use HeapAlloc or HeapFree in a multithreaded program which use the same handle to a heap?

If yes, does HeapLock block until it gets the lock?

Answer (score 2):

No. `HeapLock` acquires the lock which is used by `HeapAlloc` which you can use to lock out other threads from performing allocation and deallocation function on the specified heap but you must not use `HeapLock` before calling `HeapAlloc` or `HeapFree`.

So long as the heap was not created with `HEAP_NO_SERIALIZATION`, `HeapAlloc` and `HeapFree` are safe to use in a multithread environment.

References:

[HeapAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/site/aa366597)

[HeapLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/site/aa366702)

Comment: so am I right to say that HeapAlloc and HeapFree have synchronization built in?

Comment: Yes "Serialization ensures mutual exclusion when two or more threads attempt to simultaneously allocate or free blocks from the same heap. " from the `HeapAlloc` link. Read the Remarks section.